# How to know in ios that with which network host the device is connected

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, swift3

**How to know in ios that with which network host the device is connected.**
 I want to learn in Swift that , how can we check that at which particular network we are connected.

Comment: Use reachability framework, It will help to solve your problem

Comment: [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) from apple

Comment: AFNetworking also help which include Reachability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this custom class to get to the wifi network on which you are currently connected to :-

```
import Foundation
import SystemConfiguration.CaptiveNetwork

public class SSID {

    class func fetchSSIDInfo() -> String {

        var currentSSID = ""
        if let interfaces = CNCopySupportedInterfaces() {
            for i in 0..<CFArrayGetCount(interfaces) {
                let interfaceName: UnsafeRawPointer = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(interfaces, i)
                let rec = unsafeBitCast(interfaceName, to: AnyObject.self)
                let unsafeInterfaceData = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo("\(rec)" as CFString)
                if unsafeInterfaceData != nil {
                    let interfaceData = unsafeInterfaceData! as NSDictionary!
                    print(interfaceData)
                    currentSSID = interfaceData?.value(forKey:"SSID") as! String
                }
            }
        }
        return currentSSID
    }
}
```

You can get the Info this way :-

```
print(SSID.fetchSSIDInfo())
```